# XSLT 1.0: set variable value depending on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I want to set the value of a variable(b). If variable(a) is not empty then variable(b) equals to variable(a). If it is empty set the value to 0.00. I have tried a couple of methods but none of it works.

```
<xsl:variable name="aChecker" select="current()/money[last()]/value"/>
```

method 1:

```
<xsl:variable name="b">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$aChecker != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$aChecker"/>
        <xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="0.00"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

i tried changing the

```
<xsl:when test="$aChecker != ''">
```

to

```
<xsl:when test="not($aChecker)">
```

method 2:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$aChecker != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="b" select="$aChecker"/>
    <xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="b" select="0.00"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Your XSLT/XML is not well-formed. You are missing the `/` on the closing tag `xsl:when`.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that method #1 doesn't work? -- P.S. Your method #2 is useless, because variables are scoped to their parent element. -- Note also that `0.00` is zero.

Comment: I checked your method 1 and it does work as desired. So try posting a complete [mcve] so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: perhaps you need to clarify what you mean by "If variable(a) is not empty". The code you have written (`$aChecker != ''`) will be true if `value` exists and has a non-empty text node descendant. It will be false if value does not exist, or if it exists and only has element children.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @zx485 yep that fixed it, i missed that lol.

Comment: @michael.hor257k when i ran it nothing was on the page and yeah i need to fix the 0.00 too.

Comment: @MichaelKay by "If variable(a) is not empty" i mean if variable(a) has value. Basically what you said after the clarify thing is what i want.

Comment: "*when i ran it nothing was on the page*" A variable is a variable, it does not output anything. Please post enough code (XML, XSLT, expected output) for us to reproduce your problem.